# Krull dimension of $K[[x]]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, krull-dimension

Well, I know that this is noetherian but I don't really understand how I can get a chain of prime ideals here to find the Krull dimension and assure that it is the supremum.

Comment: What is $  K{ } $?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming $K$ is a field, $\text{dim}\,K[[X]]=1$. More generally there is the following (Theorem 15.4 from Matsumura):

> **Theorem**. Let $R$ be a noetherian ring. Then 
>   $$\text{dim}\,R[X_{1},\cdots,X_{n}]=\text{dim}\,R[[X_{1}\cdots,X_{n}]]=\text{dim}\,R+n$$

The proof for the power series case is as follows. By induction we can assume $n=1$. Any prime ideal of $R[[X]]$ is of the form $\mathfrak{M}=(\mathfrak{m},X)$ with $\mathfrak{m}=\mathfrak{M}\cap R$ a maximal ideal of $R$. Thus $\text{ht}\,\mathfrak{M}=\text{height}\,\mathfrak{m}+1$. Conversely if $\mathfrak{m}$ is a maximal ideal of $R$ then $\text{ht}\,(\mathfrak{m},X)=\text{ht}\,\mathfrak{m}+1$, which shows the equality.

Comment: Given the theorem you cited shouldn't it be $\dim K[[X]]=\dim K+1=2$ (maybe I'm missing the correct notion of $\dim$ here)?

Comment: @mrtaurho A field has Krull dimension zero.

Comment: @DietrichBurde That's was I was missing; thank you!

Comment: @Zeek Quick question, how are we using the fact that $R$ is Noetherian in this proof?