# How can I compute $m^k/m^{k+1}$ for the ideal $m=(X,Y,Z)$ in $R=\Bbb{C}[[X,Y,Z]]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, krull-dimension

> Let $R=\Bbb{C}[[X,Y,Z]]$ then I want to compute the Krull dimension of $R$.

My idea was to compute the Samuel function and bring it into a polynomial "form" then we immediately know that the Krull dimension is the degree of the polynomial.

For the Samuel function I need to compute $m^k/m^{k+1}$ for the maximal ideal $m\in R$. I know that the maximal ideal of $R$ is $m=(X,Y,Z)$.

After computing some powers I found out that $$m^j=(X^kY^lZ^{j-k-l})_{0\leq k\leq i,~~0\leq l\leq i-k}$$But now I struggle in finding out what $m^j/m^{j+1}$ is. Can someone help me how do proceed here?

Comment: Have you seen the answers [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3708683/krull-dimension-of-kx)? We have **Theorem**. Let $R$ be a Noetherian ring. Then 
$$\text{dim}\,R[X_{1},\cdots,X_{n}]=\text{dim}\,R[[X_{1}\cdots,X_{n}]]=\text{dim}\,R+n$$

Comment: @DietrichBurde the problem is, that we haven't had this theorem so I really need to do it by hand

Comment: No, the answer there gives an elementary proof, i.e., an easy induction. So no problem using it for $R=\Bbb C$.

Comment: $m^k$ is just the power series such that the coefficient of $X^a Y^b Z^c$ is $0$ whenever $a+b+c < k$. And $m^k/m^{k+1}$ is a $\Bbb{C}$-vector space with basis the $X^a Y^b Z^c$ with $a+b+c=k$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde okey I see

Comment: @reuns why do you see that?

Comment: To see what? ${}{}{}$

Comment: @reuns I don't see how we get to the fact that $m^k/m^{k+1}$ is generated as a $\Bbb{C}$ vector space. So I don't see how I can see from my $m$ how to proceed

Comment: Any power series starting at $k$ is a power series starting at $k+1$ plus some monomials at $k$

Comment: Also with $m$ maximal in $R$ then $m^k/m^{k+1}$ is a $R/m$ module or vector space, that's a general rule.

Comment: @reuns I don't get it, maybe I have the wrong picture in mind how $m^k$ looks like. Isn't an element of $m^k$ of the form $p(X,Y,Z)X^kY^lZ^{j-k-l}$ where $p\in \Bbb{C}[[X,Y,Z]]$?

Comment: @reuns I think I got it so $m^k$ is the set of all power series of order $\geq i$ and I mod out by all power series of order $\geq i+1$ and therefore what remains are all power series of degree $\leq i$?